# Cloud Foundry app state after stopping (API V2)

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to stop an app using API V2 of Cloud Foundry and **ensure the app is really stopped** before continuing.

I know stopping an app is easy with API V2 using the PUT HTTP method and passing `{"state": "stopped"}` in the body.

This method returns a summary of the app but is the `state` attribute returned the *current state* of the app or the *desired* state ?

If it's only the desired, how can I ensure my app is really stopped ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that `state` represents the desired state of the app. Thus if you move the state to `STOPPED` then it'll immediately change the state.

> The current desired state of the app. One of STOPPED or STARTED.

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/16.22.0/apps/updating_an_app.html

A stop should generally happen fast. The system doesn't want a lot of stopped apps that are not actually stopped hanging around. That wouldn't be good for stability. What happens when you request to stop an app is that the system gives the app a short period of time in which to gracefully shut down and then it sends a SIGKILL to the app (unless it shut down in the allotted time).

The default grace period is 10s, so in the worst case, the app could hang around for another 10s.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html#shutdown

> If it's only the desired, how can I ensure my app is really stopped ?

To answer your question, you don't really need to for most cases. The platform guarantees the app will shut down & it uses process signals which are core to the OS to ensure this will happen. If something went wrong and your app didn't actually stop when the SIGKILL was sent, there would be bigger problems.

That said, if you must actually check the application state, I think you have a couple of options.

1. You could look at LogCache and look for messages like:

```
   2022-06-13T09:29:49.98-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 143
   2022-06-13T09:29:49.99-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f672f785-5e69-4048-8099-9d2945ec6c37 destroying container for instance 605a495d-dada-4bab-4aa5-eea8
   2022-06-13T09:29:50.25-0400 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2022-06-13T09:29:50.45-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f672f785-5e69-4048-8099-9d2945ec6c37 successfully destroyed container for instance 605a495d-dada-4bab-4aa5-eea8
```

These are showing that the app exited with SIGTERM (143) and that the in-container proxy was SIGKILL (that's normal). You also have the cell logs to indicate that the specific container instances where your app was running have been removed. When you see those, the app has definitely been destroyed.

2. You could use the v3 API and query the processes and check the stats for the processes (I don't believe the v2 app stats will work as they don't show up for an app once it's marked as stopped in CAPI).

For example, `GET /v3/processes/<process-guid>/stats`. That would show you something like this when the process has stopped.

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "web",
      "index": 0,
      "state": "DOWN",
      "uptime": 0,
      "isolation_segment": null,
      "details": null
    }
  ]
}
```

There can be multiple processes for an app though, so you'd have to check all the processes to know when it's really stopped. You also need the guid, which you can get from fetching the list of processes for an app, see `cf curl /v3/apps/<app-guid>/processes`.

The recent cf cli v8 is using these v3 APIs to poll and check when your app starts. Version 6 of cf cli used LogCache to do the same. Both should work equally for checking when the app stops (although looking at v8, it doesn't wait for the app to actually stop).

Comment: Very complete answer, thank you very much. Will probably try the first option personaly since I'm working on a fix on terraform provider that only uses API V2. If not possible, fallback to second options which seems easier at least